# How to use Non-greedy first match in each line using grep?

Tags: regex, grep

How to modify this grep command to return only 'a1abcda1':

```
$ grep -o1 "[A-Z,a-z]1.*[A-Z,a-z]1"  myfile
a1abcda1abcdA1bcdra1
```

Comment: Only string exactly like 'a1abcda1', or string that contains 'a1abcda1'?

Comment: Do you want to include `,` in that bracket expression? Multiple ranges don't need a `,` between them.

Comment: What's the `-1` option supposed to do?

Comment: @Emanuele: only part of the string that is like 'a1abcda1' not the full line.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: I thought that will parse the first match, but clearly not doing it.

Comment: GNU grep has an `-m1` flag, maybe you meant that?

Comment: `grep -m1` is producing exact same result as `grep -o1`.

Comment: grep -o1 "a1abcda1"  myfile
does not work?

Comment: Use `grep -oP "[A-Za-z]1.*?[A-Za-z]1"  myfile | head -1`

Answer (score 1):

Make the search not greedy & use the `-P` option (PCRE):

```
grep -Po "[A-Za-z]1.*?[A-Za-z]1"  myfile
```

Comment: POSIX BRE regex does not support lazy quantifiers

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: True, thank you I've missed that.